# PHP read more read less - Magento 2

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento2

I made an read more read less script for my Magento 2 webshop. This is used on a category page where there are serval subcategorie blocks to choose, each subcategory has a description with.

The problem: if I click read more all the descriptions of the subcategories will expand in stead of only the description of the subcategory I clicked read more

I am starting to learn PHP and Magento 2 but I can't fix this, does someone know the solution?

```
  <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                <div class="more">
                                <?php  if ($_subCategory->getDescription()) {
        $string = strip_tags($_subCategory->getDescription());

        if (strlen($string) > 250) {
            // truncate string
            $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 250);
            $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readmore">Lees meer</a>';
        }
        echo $string;
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }else {?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue; 
        }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="less" style="display:none">
        <?php echo $_subCategory->getDescription(); ?>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readless">Lees minder</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('test');
        require(["jquery"],function($){
            $('.readmore').on("click",function(){
                $('.less').show();
                $('.more').hide();
            });
            $('.readless').on("click",function(){
                $('.less').hide();
                $('.more').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because, when you type `$('.less').hide();` this is grabbing *every* element with the attribute `class='less'`. This is the way I would overcome this:

Start by attaching a unique attribute to each `<div class="more">` or `<div class="less">` - in this case, we use the class attribute: (and move 'more' or 'less' to an **id**)

```
<div id="read-more-block" class="cat-<?php echo $_subCategory->getId(); ?>">
    <!-- my "read more" content -->
    <a class="link" href="#read-more-block">Read Less</a>
</div>

<div id="read-less-block" class="cat-<?php echo $_subCategory->getId(); ?>">
    <!-- my "read less" content -->
    <a class="link" href="#read-less-block">Read More</a>
</div>
```

We now have a **read-more-block** and a **read-less-block** for each subcategory. When we click the inside **link** a jQuery event should fire which will hide itself and display the other.

And then, in your jQuery:

```
$('#read-more-block .link').on('click', function() { 
    var $readLessBlock = $('#read-less-block.' + $(this).parent().attr('class'));
    $readLessBlock.show(); //Show the read less block
    $(this).parent().hide(); //Hide the read more block
});
```

..and vice versa for read less.

Comment: Thanks Adam, your code with modifications helped me fix it.